# How can I create a reminder in outlook 2019?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to create a reminder in outlook 2019 with the following schedule.

1. The reminder should be pop up every 6 hours, i.e. 8 am, 2 pm, 8 pm and 2 am.
2. The above reminder is only active on 1-15th of Jan., Apr., Jul. and Oct. every year.

Would you tell me how to set the specified schedule in outlook 2019?

Comment: You don’t. However, you could create multiple appointments to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean setting reminders for a calendar item(appointment/meeting/event) or an email in outlook? If so, as far as I know, when adding a reminder to an email or a calendar item, you can only add a fixed time reminder.

Agree with Daniel B, considering that you need to set reminders on some fixed dates every year, if you need to create a calendar item, it is recommended that you could try to create multiple calendar items and Make Recurring for every fixed date, as shown in the following figure.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.